# Boot Pop!_OS to shell, no GUI

Tags: ubuntu, boot, desktop-environments, pop-os

I have simulation that requires 30 out of my 32 GB of RAM. Unfortunately, Pop!_OS and its Desktop Environment take a little bit more than 2 GB. This means I cannot run my simulation. I tried installing other desktop environments but they still consume > 1 GB. **This is why I want to boot without the graphical interface**

I have extensively googled how to achieve this but I only find answers for Ubuntu. People talk about GRUB options but I'm using an Oryx Pro (so it's also System76 hardware) and I am using its default bootloader, not GRUB.

Comment: Before GUI starts, can you start in Terminal using Ctrl Alt F1 or F2?   That allows me to boot into Kali terminal only.

Comment: @John, all that does is switch the display. It does nothing to the running processes. The gui still runs, albeit, with only the gui login screen.

Answer (score 0):

You want `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` which will mean no gui will start on boot.

To disable the gui when already running, `systemctl isolate multi-user.target`

[systemd run levels](https://www.tecmint.com/change-runlevels-targets-in-systemd/) will give you a bit more info.